# Algorithm to find all combinations of a string, maintain order, not fixed length

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I would like to find all combinations of a string, maintaining order, but of any length. For example:

```
string_combinations("wxyz")
# => ['w', 'wx', 'wxy', 'wxyz', 'wxz', 'wy', 'wyz', 'wz', 'x', 'xy', 'xyz', 'xz', 'y', 'yz', 'z']
```

I would prefer if you could use loops only and avoid using ruby methods like `#combination` as I am trying to find the cleanest way to implement this if I come across it in another language.

Is there a way to do this in less than O(n^3)? My initial thought is something like:

```
def string_combinations(str)
    result = []

    (0...str.length).each do |i|
        result << str[i]
        ((i+1)...str.length).each do |j|
            result << str[i] + str[j]
            ((j+1)...str.length).each do |k|
                result << str[i] + str[j..k]
                # Still not covering everything.
            end
        end
    end

    result
end
```

Comment: Have a look at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12615/write-a-program-which-performs-brute-force-letter-combination-until-the-word-pa for ideas how it could be achieved.

Comment: "combinations ... maintaining order"--Contradiction. Which do you want?

Comment: How is that a contradiction? Please explain. I am asking to maintain order in reference to the string, not in reference to the output (i.e. combination, not permutation) as would be made clear by my example output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways it could be done without making use of `Array#combination`. I've also included code for the case when `combination` is permitted (#3)<sup>1</sup>.

**1. Map each of the numbers between `1` and `2**n-1` (`n` being the length of the string) to a unique combination of characters from the string**

```
def string_combinations(str)
  arr = str.chars
  (1..2**str.length-1).map do |n|
    pos = n.bit_length.times.map.with_object([]) { |i,a| a << i if n[i] == 1 }
    arr.values_at(*pos).join
  end.sort
end

string_combinations("wxyz")
  # => ["w", "wx", "wxy", "wxyz", "wxz", "wy", "wyz", "wz",
  #     "x", "xy", "xyz", "xz", "y", "yz", "z"]
```

Discrete probability theory provides us with the equation

```
sum(i = 1 to n) ( |i| C(n,i) ) == 2^n - 1
```

where `C(n,i)` is "the number of combinations of n things taken i at a time".

If the given string is `"wxyz"`, `n = "wxyz".length #=> 4`, so there are `2**4 - 1 #=> 15` combinations of one or more characters from this string. Now consider any of the numbers between 1 and 16, say 11, which is `0b1011` in binary. Converting this to an array of binary digits, we obtain:

```
bin_arr = [1,0,1,1]
```

We now pluck out each character of `wxyz` for which the corresponding index position in `bin_arr` equals `1`, namely

```
["w", "y", "z"]
```

and then join those elements to form a string:

```
["w", "y", "z"].join #=> "wyz"
```

Since each number `1` to `15` corresponds to a distinct combination of one or more characters from this string, , we can obtain all such combinations by repeating the above calculation for each the numbers between `1` and `15`.

No matter which method you use, the resulting array will contain `2**n - 1` elements, so you are looking at `O(2**str.length)`.

**2. Use recursion**

```
def string_combinations(str)
  (combos(str) - [""]).sort
end

def combos(str)
  return [str, ""] if str.length==1
  forward = combos str[1..-1]
  [*forward, *[str[0]].product(forward).map(&:join)]
end

string_combinations("wxyz")
  # => ["w", "wx", "wxy", "wxyz", "wxz", "wy", "wyz", "wz",
  #     "x", "xy", "xyz", "xz", "y", "yz", "z"]
```

Notice that

```
combos("wxyz")
  #=> ["z", "", "yz", "y", "xz", "x", "xyz", "xy",
  #    "wz", "w", "wyz", "wy", "wxz", "wx", "wxyz", "wxy"]
```

includes an empty string, which must be removed, and the array needs sorting. Hence the need to separate out the recursive method `combos`.

**3. Use [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination)**

Here we invoke `arr.combination(n)` for all values of `n` between `1` and `arr.size` and return a (flattened) array comprised of all `n` return values.

```
def string_combinations(str)
  a = str.chars
  (1..str.size).flat_map { |n| a.combination(n).map(&:join) }.sort
end

string_combinations "wxyz"
  # => ["w", "wx", "wxy", "wxyz", "wxz", "wy", "wyz", "wz",
  #     "x", "xy", "xyz", "xz", "y", "yz", "z"]
```

<sup><sub>1 Since I wrote it before realizing that's not what the OP wanted. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</sub></sup>

Comment: As I stated in my post, I am looking to implement this specifically without relying on `#combination`.

Comment: Damon's comment refers to my original solution, in which I had only included #3 above. (I had overlooked his reference to `combination` in the question.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. It's been really helpful. Voting this as accepted as I believe it is the most complete in offering multiple approaches. Thanks for taking the time to be so thorough!

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple solution using a stack (I can't provide ruby-code though):

```
string inp
list result

//initialize stack
stack s
s.push(0)

while(!s.isEmpty())
    int tmp = s.peek()

    //the current value is higher than the max-index -> shorten prefix
    if tmp >= inp.length()
        s.pop()

        //increment the last character of the prefix
        if !s.isEmpty()
            s.push(s.pop() + 1)

        continue

    //build the result-string from the indices in the stack
    //note that the indices in the stack are reverse (highest first)!!!
    result.add(buildString(inp , s)

    //since we aren't at the end of the string, we can append another character to the stack
    s.push(tmp + 1)
```

The basic idea would be to maintain a stack of positions from which characters will be taken. This stack has the property that each element in the stack is a larger number than the next element in the stack. Thus the ordering of the stack is maintained. If we reach a number that is equal to the string-length, we eliminate that number and increment the next number, thus moving on to the next prefix.

```
E.g.:
stack                                    string
0 (init)                                 a b c (init)
0                                        a
0 1                                      a b
0 1 2                                    a b c
0 2                                      a c
1                                        b
1 2                                      b c
2                                        c
```

The peek of the stack would represent the character of the input-string that is modified, the rest of the stack represents the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the algorithm could be expressed in English as:

```
"w", followed by "w" + all combinations of "xyz", followed by
"x", followed by "x" + all combinations of "yz", followed by
etc.
```

In other words, there is a notion of a "prefix" and then recursion on the "remaining chars". With that in mind, here is a Ruby solution:

```
def combine_with_prefix(prefix, chars)
  result = []
  chars.each_with_index do |ch, i|
    result << "#{prefix}#{ch}"
    result.concat(combine_with_prefix(result.last, chars[(i + 1)..-1]))
  end
  result
end

def string_combinations(str)
  combine_with_prefix(nil, str.chars)
end

string_combinations("wxyz")
# => ["w", "wx", "wxy", "wxyz", "wxz", "wy", "wyz", "wz", "x", "xy", "xyz", "xz", "y", "yz", "z"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to think about this: You start with an input string *s* having length *n*. From that you calculate the set of strings that can be produced by removing one character from *s*. That set has *n* members. For each of those members you perform the same operation: Calculate the set of strings that can be produced by removing one character. Each of those sets has *n-1* members. For each of those *n(n-1)* members, perform the operation again, and so on until *n* is 1. The result is the union of all of the calculated sets.

For example, suppose your starting string is `abcd` (*n* = 4) The set of strings that can be produced by removing one character is (`bcd`, `acd`, `abd`, `abc`). That's 4 operations. Repeating the operation for each of those strings yields 4 sets of 3 members each (4x3 = 12 operations), each of which has length 2. Repeating again yields 12 sets of 2 members each (4x3x2 = 24 operations), each having length 1. That's the magic number, so we round up all of those strings, throw out the duplicates, and we've got our answers. In the end we did 4+4x3+4x3x2 = 40 operations.

That holds true for every length of string. If we have 5 characters we do 5+5x4+5x4x3+5x4x3x2 = 205 operations. For 6 characters it's 1,236 operations. I leave it to you to figure out what that equates to in big-*O* notation.

This boils down to a really simple recursive algorithm:

```
def comb(str)
  [ str,
    *if str.size > 1
      str.each_char.with_index.flat_map do |_,i|
        next_str = str.dup
        next_str.slice!(i)
        comb(next_str)
      end
    end
  ]
end

p comb("wxyz").uniq.sort
# => [ "w", "wx", "wxy", "wxyz", "wxz", "wy", "wyz", "wz",
#      "x", "xy", "xyz", "xz", "y", "yz", "z" ]
```

We end up throwing out a lot with `uniq`, though, which tells us we can save a lot of cycles by memoizing:

```
def comb(str, memo={})
  return memo[str] if memo.key?(str)

  [ str,
    *if str.size > 1
      str.each_char.with_index.flat_map do |_,i|
        next_str = str.dup
        next_str.slice!(i)
        memo[str] = comb(next_str, memo)
      end
    end
  ]
end

p comb("wxyz").uniq.sort
```

In case you're curious, with memoization the inner loop is reached 23 times for a 4-character input versus 41 without memoization; 46 vs. 206 times for 5 characters; 87 vs. 1,237 times for 6; and 162 vs. 8,653 for 7. Fairly significant, I think.